# programmable naming variables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, excel, openxml

I have an Excel Automation project using Open XML SDK 2.0 in ASP.NET. I use Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool for generate code for my excel file. Сontains lines such as

```
row9.Append(cell1043);
row9.Append(cell1044);
row9.Append(cell1045);
row9.Append(cell1046);
row9.Append(cell1047);
row9.Append(cell1048);
```

But I`m want use cycle

```
For(i)
  For(j)
    row[i].Append(cell[j]);
```

Any guidelines or suggestions?

Comment: Did you check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh180830(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it although your question is not that clear

```
    For r As Integer = 0 To 9
        For c As Integer = 0 To 9
            xlWSheet.Cells(r, c).value = "foo"
        Next
    Next
```